# WiFi disconnecting on 18.04 Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I tried formatting and reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04 / Ubuntu 20.04 / Fedora 33 / Fedora 32.
I also tried different driver updates, 3rd party drivers from github etc nothing works.
The weird thing is that it runs on a dual boot and on Windows 10 it works just fine. Before I installed it on dual boot, it was running on Ubuntu 20.04 and then the problems started to appear. I tried replacing the WIFI adapter, this Qualcomm is the 5th adapter I've put in.
The other adapters were 2x Intel, Broadcom and some Chinese branded adapter.

I can select my SSID in the network-manager, but when I click, or nothing happens, or it tries to connect but it can't. After several reboots it sometimes connects, then after a few minutes of 10kb/s download speed, it just disconnects. This Qualcomm adapter promises a 400+ mb/s download speed. My Wireless AP supports a 1Gb/s speed. And I'm sitting next to the AP.

Can someone help me on this one? I'm looking for solutions for this for a few months now.
Thanks in advance,
S.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be on the windows side. Try booting into windows, go to power options in settings, go to additional settings, find where 'set what power button does' and disable the fast boot option and save those settings. Then boot back into linux.
When the 'fast start' option is enabled, windows doesnt really 'shut down' when you ask it to, and since windows is running as well, linux cant detect the wifi card because it is already in use by the windows partition.
Atleast that is my understanding of it. Hope that makes sense to you.
Good luck!

Comment: It seems to do the trick as of right now, I'll keep an eye on it. In fact, now there is a questionmark in my 'wifi bows', sometimes there are 3 dots